# key/value combinations in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For each key in the dictionary I would like to create a string of the matching values.  Being `key+value` into a string variable.

```
d={'df0.':['a_wfa','b_wfa'],'df1.':['a_wfa','b_wfa'],'df2.':['a_wfu','b_wfu']}
```

With desired results of:

```
a_wfa='df0.a_wfa,df1.a_wfa'
b_wfa='df0.b_wfa,df1.b_wfa'
a_wfu='df2.a_wfu'
b_wfu='df2.b_wfu'
```

Comment: In the length of the list is set or can change?

Comment: length of the list can change.

Comment: I meant the length of the nested , meaning can it be list of list , if so you will need to use recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do sth like this:

```py
array={'df0.':['a_wfa','b_wfa'],'df1.':['a_wfa','b_wfa'],'df2.':['a_wfu','b_wfu']}

finalDic ={}
for element in array:
    for insideElement in array[element]:
        if insideElement in finalDic.keys(): 
            finalDic[insideElement].append(element + insideElement)
        else:
            finalDic[insideElement] = [element + insideElement]

print(finalDic)
```

And get this:

```py
{
    'a_wfa': ['df0.a_wfa', 'df1.a_wfa'],
    'b_wfa': ['df0.b_wfa', 'df1.b_wfa'],
    'a_wfu': ['df2.a_wfu'],
    'b_wfu': ['df2.b_wfu']
}
```